# How to upload app bundle (made by freelance contractor) to Google play console?

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, android-studio, google-play-console

I had a friend take a design of mine for an app, and then build it with React Native, then send me the files so I can upload it to the Google Play Store.

I'm having trouble. I have the raw files, an AAB file, and an APK file. I don't have the compiler or whatever my friend used to turn the raw files into the AAB/APK files, yet.

The AAB file and APK file seem to need to be edited by me (version number/name) but won't let me.

I also am totally lost with Google's Play App Signing, which doesn't seem to let me do with these files either.

I'm guessing I'm a few steps away from solving these issues, but can anyone point me in the right direction?

I've tried several walk-throughs but I keep getting errors.

Comment: do you have any knowledge in coding? if yes then can you at least tell me if the app is made using kotlin, react-native or hybrid (cordova/capacitor) ?

Comment: Yes, React native

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.